# Check if value exists in python xarray dataset

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm cutting up xarrays into small cubes of data for a machine learning process and am trying to filter out cubes with no-data values in them.

I want to keep the memory footprint small and have assigned an unlikely value of -999 to no-data values. This is done to keep things `int16` instead of requiring a larger type for `nan`

**Question:  What is the best way to check if -999 exists in an xarray.Dataset?**

Here is what I have:

```
(dataset == -999).any()
```

will yeild:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
    var_a      bool True
    var_b      bool True
    var_c      bool False
```

after which I would likely have to select something like `var_a`. My code would end up looking like this:

```
def is_clean(dataset):
    return (dataset == -999).any().var_a is True
```

Maybe I'm still fresh when it comes to Xarrays, but I can't find a nicer way to do this in the docs. What bit of structural knowledge about xarrays am I missing that keeps me from being ok with my current solution? Any hints?

Comment: `return (dataset.var_a == -999).any()` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My issue is that `return (dataset.var_a == -999).any()` will return an `xr.Dataset` not a boolean value.

Comment: What is the dimensionality of the returned `xr.Dataset`?

Comment: The section above shows actual output. There is no dimensionality. Just three variables with boolean values.

Comment: I was refering to the dimensionality of my construct.  I don't have XArray installed.

Comment: Remote network is down. I was running this remotely. If I recall correctly that should work. However, I would like the remove the notion that I know any of the variable names in the first place to make the function more general.  (I'll have to get back to you tomorrow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions on xarray objects generally return new xarray objects of the same type. This means `(dataset.var_a == -999).any()` results in a scalar `xarray.DataArray` object.

Like scalar NumPy arrays, scalar DataArray objects can be inboxed by calling builtin types on them like `bool()` or `float()`. This happens implicitly inside the condition of an `if` statement, for example. Also like NumPy arrays, you can unbox a scalar DataArray of any dtype by with the `.item()` method.

To check every data variable in a Dataset, you'll either need to iterate over the Dataset using dictionary like access, e.g.,

```
def is_clean(dataset):
    return all((v != -999).all() for v in dataset.data_vars.values())
```

Or you could convert the whole Dataset into a single DataArray by calling `.to_array()`, e.g.,

```
def is_clean(dataset):
    return bool(dataset.to_array() != -999).all())
```

To avoid excess memory usage, you might convert to an array *after* reducing, which is a little longer but not too bad:

```
def is_clean(dataset):
    return bool((dataset != -999).all().to_array().all())
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer.  This was my expectation given what I have learned of pandas/numpy.  Guess I should install xarray, and learn a few things.